# Using Apache mod_rewrite produces incorect response or 500 error response

Tags: linux, apache, single-page-application

I am trying to create a Single Page App that works this way:

> If the HTTP Request header **Accept** is set to **application/json** server service.php else server index.html

Here is my current Config File:

```
<Location "/" >

    RewriteEngine on

    # JSON response
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/json [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . service.php [L]

    # HTML Response
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/json [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.html [L]

</Location>
```

I also need to handle paths("/") for SPA

Some of the methods I have tried from Googling around give a 500/400 response code and I have tried to skeem through the Docs whole day.

Please check my configuration and point me to the right direction. Also if posible exaplain briefly how mod_rewrite works. I am using a linux computer.

Comment: Where are you putting these directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work for you in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# ignore all files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# JSON response
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/json [NC]
RewriteRule . service.php [L]

# HTML Response
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

I wrote mine this way and placed it in VertualHost context:

```
RewriteEngine on

# JSON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/json [NC]
RewriteRule . /service.php [L]

# Everything else
# Note: for some reason, if the code below is not in Location directive, js & css are loaded with text/html MIME
<Location "/" >
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</Location>
```

Comment: It looks like these directives are perhaps being used in the server config, not `.htaccess`?

Comment: Yes it appears from OP's edited section that directives are being used in `VirtualHost` section.

Comment: They are in the server's config file, in `VirtualHost`